# How to build somewhat complicated recyclerview layout without ugly codes?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

[image: the picture above] The picture above is what I am building, and I have already finish the default layout. I am using `GridLayoutManager` with a simple formula(`position - 3 * (position / 3)`) + `switch` to calculate the span of each cell, and then the adapter also calls the same formula to get the result accordingly to use the correct layout file: 1:1 or 16:9 (using `ConstraintLayout` + `ImageView`). There is also a `ItemDecoration` to add 4dp of white space between each cell.

Now when I start to build the smallest width = 600 configuration, some problem occur: since there is a small margin between each elements, the size of the wider one is actually slightly narrower than 2:1, which means the wider cell will be slightly taller than the 1:1 cell. For example, the perfect ratio of the wider cell in 600dp should be 398:198 when there is a 4dp margin between the 2 images.

I know that I can always just merge multiple layout files into 1 to make sure each row will share the same height, but since I would like to continue to add more configurations, the code will probably become super messy at the end. So my question is:

1) Is it possible to do it with GridLayoutManager? If yes, how?

2) Even if GridLayoutManager can do the job, is there any better method to do that? A custom LayoutManager maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh of course there's already a library that does that: https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager

Still trying it out but so far it seems to do exactly what I need to do!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with GridLayoutManager but its complicated. Android provides StaggeredGridLayoutManager to implement such type of views. It makes easy to implement with recyclerview.

```
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//set adapter to recyclerview
```

For example 
https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html

Official docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: but I don't think you can make 2x1 or 3x1 blocks with staggered grid, right? all it can do is Pinterest style list

Comment: found an example(https://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/) of staggered grid that can expand a cell to full width, which is neat, but that still don't solve the problem of making a 2x1 cell in a 3 column layout